# Using divs to create a javascript event system; Is this a good solution?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I am building a game and was wondering how this design works for an event system.

I am using the same div to emit all events to, and to listen to all events.

```
  const eventManagerDiv = document.getElementById("event-manager");
  eventManagerDiv.addEventListener(
    "move to",
    function (e) {
      ... do things
    },
    false
  );
```

```
const emitEvent = (eventName, detail) => {
  const eventManagerEvent = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: detail });
  const eventManagerDiv = document.getElementById("event-manager");
  eventManagerDiv.dispatchEvent(eventManagerEvent);
};

emitEvent("move to", { x: x, z: z });
```

Will this design scale? Does it have glaring issues? What is another solution to this problem you might recommend?

Comment: hmmm, this sounds like something for [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm wondering if events are even needed if you are arbitrarily attaching them to an element that didn't even produce the event in the first place. For example, instead of calling `emitEvent` you could call the function that you are trying to run when that event was created.

Comment: If you just want something that behaves as an event emitter, you can also use [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) directly.